# A special bijection between $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there any bijection $\eta:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with the property $\min\{x,y\}\leq \eta(x,y)\leq \max\{x,y\}$?

Comment: Sorry, the condition $x\neq y$ is forgotten?

Answer (score 3):

That would have $\eta(x,x)=x$ which would use up all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Can you give an $\eta$ with explicit formula?

Comment: There **isn't** an $\eta$.

Comment: Sorry, the condition $x\neq y$ is forgotten

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown. Do you have any answer for it by consideration the condition $x\neq y$?